# MVC4 Web Api Castle Windsor Container.Resolve AllComponents count = 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

**Current Code**

```
public class SystemUserController : ApiController
{
   ISystemUserDataAccess dataAccess;
   public SystemUserController(ISystemUserDataAccess userDataAccess)
   {
      dataAccess = userDataAccess;
   }

  //Other api methods
}
```

And ISystemUserDataAccess is the interface which contains all the data access methods. I have following installer code, which is being called by the Global.asax

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
   {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
           container.Register(
                    Component.For(typeof(IConnectDB)).ImplementedBy(typeof(ConnectDB)),
                    Component.For(typeof(ISystemUserDataAccess)).ImplementedBy(typeof(SystemUserDataAccess));

         }
    }


public class ApiControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container,
        Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
             .BasedOn<ApiController>()
             .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
    }
```

Container Initialization at Global.asax

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

It is all working fine. **userDataAccess** get injected properly and i can call all the DataAccess method without any problem.

My Data Access class looks like below.

```
public class SystemUserDataAccess : ISystemUserDataAccess
{
   IConnectDB connectionManager;
   public SystemUserDataAccess(IConnectDB connection)
   {
      connectionManager = connection;
   }

   //Data access  methods
}
```

**Actual Problem**

Now I need an instance of SystemUserDataAccess within a non ApiController class (this is a static class). When I tried below code, but it is giving an exception, saying it couldnt find any component registered.

```
 IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
 var asas = container.Resolve<ISystemUserDataAccess>();
```

When I inspect the container object, "All component" property is 0. Which is why it is throwing the error. What am I doing wrong here? Do i need another installer for that non ApiController class?

Comment: Hello Jenon, I don't see any registration in your code between creating the container and the resolve. If this is the same in your real code that would explain why no component are registered.Another thing is that you won't be able the lifestylePerWebRequest if you don't resolve the components in a web request.

Comment: I was actually thinking as I have already register in the "RepositoriesInstaller", I dont have to do it again in the other places. Looks like I am missing an important concept?

Comment: Just to make sure, you understand my question, I have the dependencies injected properly using the Global.asax, That is what is in RepositoriesInstaller. It is all fine and working when I make a request to the API method. What I am trying to do now is to instantiate an object which has a dependency from a non ApiController static class. Can i do that?

Comment: Once you register a component in the container it will stay registered in that container. In the code above it seem like you are instantiating a new (empty) container.

Comment: Hi Marwijn, yes thats true. But I have the container initialization code at the global.asax. (I have edited the question). Do I have to initialize a new container if I want to use it in another place other than a APIController? How do I get a reference to the container initialized in the global.asax from the other places of the code?

Comment: My first recommendation would be don't use a static class. However if you do assign the ISystemUserDataAccess to a property of this class from you asax file. You will need to register a second component with a different lifestyle(singleton) for this as you can't resolve a PerWebRequestComponent without a WebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `container.Install(FromAssembly.This());` in `global.asax`, use `container.install(new RepositoriesInstaller());`